# Bool array filled with incorrect values after initialization

Tags: c++, arrays

**Short Question:**

I initialize the value in an array and show that it's a certain value, then the next time I check it the value has changed. What have I done to make that happen?

**Details:**

In the interest of learning how to code, I'm practicing random programming challenges online. The current one is to take a string of numbers and determine if it's "magic". This involves having only one of each number in the string, and going through the whole string by having one number point to another (like if you had 113, first 1 would count to second 1, which would count to the 3, which would count to itself).

Going through the number works out well, and I got that working without a problem, and I figured since I was going through the number this way already, I would make a bool array to count whether a digit had been used. An array of 10 bools, and array[i] would be a bool value saying whether i had been used. Probably not the best implementation, but it seemed simple.

The array "visited" works, but "numUsed" doesn't seem to work. I've initialized every value just in case that was an issue, and when testing I've checked every value starts as 0. When actually checking the array though, the values aren't correct.

The following is my test outputting. The first string of numbers is me printing off the "numUsed" array, to show I've initialized it all zero. Then the number I'm checking, the value of the number at the first check, and then the value of the numUsed array at that

```
0000000000 - 10[0][0]
0000000000 - 11[1][1]
0000000000 - 12[2][254]
0000000000 - 13[3][40]
0000000000 - 14[4][0]
0000000000 - 15[5][10]
0000000000 - 16[6][0]
0000000000 - 17[7][0]
0000000000 - 18[8][0]
0000000000 - 19[9][0]
0000000000 - 20[2][254]
```

And the Code:

```
bool visited[7] = {0};
bool numUsed[10] = {0};

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << (numUsed[i] = false);
}

int charPlace = 0;
cout << " - " << numString;
for(int i = 0; i < numString.length(); i++) {
    charPlace = (charPlace + numString.at(charPlace)) % (numString.length());

    if(visited[charPlace] == false) visited[charPlace] = true;
    else                            return false;

    cout << "[" << numString.at(charPlace) << "][" << numUsed[(char)numString.at(charPlace)] << "]";
    if(numUsed[numString.at(i)] == false) numUsed[numString.at(i)] = true;
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `cout << (numUsed[i] = false);` is performing an assignment.

Comment: Yep, I want it to make it false to start. The trouble is it doesn't appear to stay false after that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is that `numString.at(charPlace)` is a `char` like `'1'` and not an integer like `1`.

Comment: Ah thanks! I figured there was a char or int issue, but didn't think of it like a number with quotes. I dug into it a little more and found that adding a  " - '0' " to it did the proper math to make it the right number.